# Exporting plots to PDF from R

Tags: r, pdf, plot, ggplot2

I have scoured this site and others for an answer and can't seem to get the PDF portion of the code to work and help is greatly appreciated.

This code works fine, it loops through and creates plots for each industry in the RStudio Output:

```
   gg <- list()
   #make the plots, facet by client on each page - works well
   for (p in 1:length(df)){
   gg[[p]] <- ggplot(data = df[[p]],  aes(x = MonthsActive, y = Participation, color = CommClient)) + 
      ylim(0,1) + geom_line(size = 0.8) + 
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,13)) + 
      facet_wrap(~ClientName, scales="fixed") + 
      scale_color_hue(l = 45) + 
      ggtitle(sprintf("Participation Rate for %s for First Year",params[p]))
    plot(gg[[p]])
    }
```

Now when I wrap the PDF function around this I can't get it to output the plots.  I have tested the destination path (Windows System) and when printed it looks okay.  At one point, I got blank unreadable PDFs so the path seems to work. This code does not create individual PDFs:

```
 gg <- list()
 #make the plots, facet by client on each page
  for (p in 1:length(df)){

 #set the file path by name - when using print looks fine

    myPath <- file.path("Q:","DataScience", "ParticipationPlots", paste(params[p], ".pdf", sep="")) 

    #set pdf as device and make individual PDFs

    pdf(file = myPath, onefile = F, paper = "USr", width = 11, height = 8.5)

    #this code is the same as above that works except for dev.off() at end
    gg[[p]] <- ggplot(data = df[[p]],  aes(x = MonthsActive, y = Participation, color = CommClient)) + 
      ylim(0,1) + geom_line(size = 0.8) + 
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,13)) + 
      facet_wrap(~ClientName, scales="fixed") + 
      scale_color_hue(l = 45) + 
      ggtitle(sprintf("Participation Rate for %s for First Year",params[p]))
    plot(gg[[p]])
    }
 dev.off()
```

Comment: try using `ggsave` to save plots generated, cleaner to use IMO.

Comment: you should use `print` not `plot` for grid graphics https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f

Answer (score 3):

dev.off() needs to be inside the loop